# How to make conditional column in Power BI

Tags: vba, powerbi

There are two groups: IDnumber and Procedure. An IDnumber has any number of procedures associated with it, and each one is listed on its own row. One of the procedures is the most important (TKA), and i want to be able to create a third column that would label every row of an IDnumber with "TKA" if "TKA" is the name of one of the procedures of a specific IDnumber. How can I do this? Picture below shows what I want. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Well, what have you tried after doing your research?

Comment: i dont know how to make a list with dependencies on two different columns ): this is my first time using powerBI and i dont really know how to direct my research

Comment: Your question is not about grouping (aggregating). It is all about adding conditional column. Please search the web for that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Edit Queries > Add Column > Custom Column`and use the following expression (M):

```
Groups = if [Procedure] = "TKA" then "TKA" else "Other"
```

or in the fields pane right click on your table and chose `New Column` (DAX):

```
Groups = IF('YourTable'[Procedure] = "TKA"; "TKA"; "Others")
```

Comment: i dont think this would affect all rows

Comment: Sure it does. Did you try it? Btw, you would have found an answer in under 1 minute of google search.